# Remove signin-oidc from redirect url

Tags: identityserver4

Everywhere for IdentityServer4, redirect_uri contains **/signin-oidc** as callback after successful authorization.

But as per oidc specifications redirect_uri has no constraint to have signin-oidc suffix.
Is there a way to remove this check or functionality and redirect to what is being supplied as redirect_uri?

Or am I missing something?
I cant understand the purpose of fixing **signin-oidc** in IDS4 callback

Answer (score 2):

`/signin-oidc` is just the default path for the .Net OIDC client middleware but it's easily changed via the `OpenIdConnectOptions.CallbackPath` setting.

Doing so is neccessary if registering multiple schemes of the same type.

Comment: I will try out the same.

Comment: I can't see such option in IdentityServer4 options. The ids server still not allows redirecturi without signin-oidc

Comment: "Doing so is necessary if registering multiple schemes of the same type" -- can you explain why this is the case?